# Publishing .NET 5 Project including COM References

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 Project running. I have added a COM Reference to the Zebra Scanner SDK. The SDK is built for the .Net Framework but I want it to run on .NET 5. I can build the project on my machine, as the SDK is installed on my machine.

The problem now is, that I want to build the project including the reference. So I can easily copy the generated .dll and .exe files to a new computer. Without having the need to install the Scanner SDK there.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe to create a dll from the COM Reference and use that?

[SDK Info](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html)

[Scanner SDK Sample Projects](https://github.com/zebra-technologies/Scanner-SDK-for-Windows-Code-Snippets/tree/master/CSharp)

Comment: Are you looking for regfree (registration free) com interop? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registration-free-com-interop - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#enabling-regfree-com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution for the Zebra Scanner SDK. In this case you can identify the SDK location and there find the sample projects. They contain a InterOp.CoreScanner.dll.

Just copy this file to your project folder, use it as a reference and you are good to go.

Comment: Hi, @Karl Wolf. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: Hi, @Karl your answer was tremendously helpful for me. I have sent you a chat invite if that's okay